# Using Tor + Privoxy to scrape google shopping results: How to avoid block?

Tags: python, scrape, tor

I have installed `Tor + Privoxy` on my server and they're working fine! (Tested).
But now when I try to use `urllib2 (python)` to scrape google shopping results, using proxy of course, I always get blocked by google (sometimes 503 error, sometimes 403 error). So anyone have any solutions can help me avoid that problem? It would be very appreciated!!

The source code that I am using:

```
 _HEADERS = {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate',
      'Connection': 'close',
      'DNT': '1'
  }

  request = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.com/#q=iphone+5&tbm=shop", headers=self._HEADERS)

  proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)

  try:
      response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
      html = response.read()
      print html

   except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
       print e.code
       print e.reason
```

Note that: When I don't use proxy, it can work fine!

Comment: As people noted here Google is blocking Tor as it's being used by so many people. The topic of scraping is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results/22703153#22703153

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed stem, the controller library for Tor?
In just a few lines of code you can request a new identity from Tor. See:

https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor

Simply use exceptions to catch your 403 and 503 errors and handle them by requesting a new identity, as shown in the link above. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Google blocks many of exit Tor nodes because Google receive many requests from them.
So this error is question of probability, change your exit Tor node until find one without be blocked by Google.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#GoogleCAPTCHA

Comment: Anyway, if you find a working exit node, sleep 15 seconds between requests to prevent to be blocked after some hundred of requests.